# Are Hirelings Looted From Your Dead Body?

Tags: munchkin

At first we said that he simply loses his item, and sticks around until you're respawned...but then my friend changed his mind and thought that, given we were in a *real* dungeon/monster/treasure situation, he'd simply whistle over the hireling, who would be lost and afraid without a hero escorting him around. Listening to him, it almost seemed as if he had the hirelings best interest in mind while crafting his argument....*hmmmmm*.

I gave him points for originality, but told him I'd have to consult with the community here first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hirelings are just cards, like other cards. [The rules](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/rules/) for looting are quite clear - you lose all the cards you had in play. So not only do you lose anything he's carrying, you lose your Hireling too (he runs off somewhere)!

> **Death**
>
> If you die, you lose all your stuff.
>   You keep your Class(es), Race(s), and Level (and any Curses that were affecting you
>   when you died) – your new character will look just like your old one.
>   If you have Half- Breed or Super Munchkin, keep those as well.
>
> **Looting The Body:** Lay out your hand beside the cards you had in play. Starting
>   with the one with the highest Level, each other player chooses one
>   card . . . in case of ties in level, roll a die. If your corpse runs
>   out of cards, tough. After everyone gets one card, the rest are
>   discarded.
>
> Dead characters cannot receive cards for any reason, not
>   even Charity, and cannot level up.
>
> Your new character appears when the
>   next player begins his turn, and can help others in combat . . . but
>   you have no cards.

Comment: All of this is just reminding me that I forgot to sacrifice my hireling, and instead failed my run away. `<sigh>`